# Positive side effect of classes with package-private constructors and the corresponding objects instantiated via Guice?

Tags: java, guice

Wondering if this is a +ve side effect of package-private constructors of the objects instantiated by Guice.

I have a class which looks like

```
class Foo { //note the access specifier

 private Bar1 iCannotBeNull;
 private Bar2 iCannotBeNullEither;  

 @Inject
 Foo(Bar1 bar1, Bar2 bar2) {//note the access specifier
      this.iCannotBeNull = Objects.requireNonNull(bar1, "null injected");
      this.iCannotBeNullEither = Objects.requireNonNull(bar2, "null injected");
  }   

}
```

Going by https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable, looks like I can technically get rid of null checks, since I am ensuring through package-private constructors (and of course Guice module residing in the same package) that objects of Foo are created by Guice only, and Guice will never inject null.

```
@Inject
 Foo(Bar1 bar1, Bar2 bar2) {//note the access specifier
      this.iCannotBeNull = bar1;
      this.iCannotBeNullEither = bar2;
  }
```

Is my understanding correct, or have I just overlooked something very obvious here?

Comment: If you can guarantee that you will only ever construct the instances via guice, I suppose you could. But if you construct it in any other way (using some other DI framework without such a guarantee, or invoking the ctor directly (such as in a test)), then you would be able to pass in null, and it would fail later, when it would be hard to debug.

Comment: I agree with your concern about test cases. Especially since test cases may not necessarily use Guice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miško Hevery, an agile coach at Google, claims that these `checkNotNull` assertions inhibit testing slightly in [this blog](https://testing.googleblog.com/2009/02/to-assert-or-not-to-assert.html).

For example, it is often useful to pass in `null` for dependencies that one does not care about for a test:

```
testSecureHouse() {
  Door door = new Door();
  Window window = new Window();
  House house = new House(door, window,
             null, null, null, null);

  house.secure();

  assertTrue(door.isLocked());
  assertTrue(window.isClosed());
}
```

If you subscribe to this view, an alternative to `checkNotNull` is to use the `@Nullable`,`@NonNull`, and `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` annotations:

```
@Inject
Foo(@NonNull Bar1 bar1, @NonNull Bar2 bar2) {
    //
}
```

If you do this, most IDEs or lint checks will give a warning when a developer tries to pass `null` to the ctor for `Foo`.

Overall though, it seems like you will have to balance convenience and the risk of a developer making a mistake by passing in `null`. Since you have organised your packages well and are using access modifiers to prevent unintended usages, the risk for your particular situation (a package-private constructor which will only called by the Guice module) seems quite low.

If your `Foo` class was part of a public API this would be quite different and the class would definitely benefit from the assertions and failing fast.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not get rid of the null checks because as it is stated, the checks represent the **general, not related to Guice,** fast-fail mechanism:

> `Preconditions.checkNotNull` can be used to fast-fail if a null reference is found, <…>
>
> — [UseNullable · google/guice Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable).

**Additionally**, Guice has **its specific mechanism** to handle nullable and non-nullable dependencies using the appropriate annotations:

> Guice forbids `null` by default. It will refuse to inject `null`, failing with a `ProvisionException` instead. If `null` is permissible by your class, you can annotate the field or parameter with `@Nullable`. Guice recognizes any `@Nullable` annotation, like `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.Nullable` or `javax.annotation.Nullable`.
>
> — [UseNullable · google/guice Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable).

Comment: Which possibly implies that it is wrong to assume that the instances will be created via Guice only, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. For example, you may want to instantiate an object «manually» — using its constructor directly.